# how do i get values from a grid of multiple groups of radio buttons?

Tags: google-apps-script

my code is long but i think my question is simple:  How can i build a google GUI to show a grid of multiple groups of radio buttons. 
in essence, i want to build something that is like:

Jane Smith:
   Question 1:    radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4
   Question 2:    radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4

John Doe:
   Question 1:    radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4
   Question 2:    radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4

etc.etc...

I have the whole code written to dynamically create the page and all the nested for loops for the logic to read each group of radio buttons back out into an array after the user submits to then be able to parse and have my way with it.

But how do i get the variables of the radio buttons themselvse?

the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444798/how-to-know-which-radio-button-is-selected) seem overly complicated as it is about 10 lines of code that would need to be injected into each layer of my 3 layer deep for loops to make that work, i think.  unless i'm thinking about it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

RadioButtons [must have the same name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_radiobutton) (be part of the same group) to work as expected (exclusive-OR) so the solution to assign a client handler to each of them that sets a value to a hidden widget (or a textBox) is, AFAIK, the only working solution if you're not using a form.
The code is not so complicated and in your case it will be the same for each question so you could easily implement it in your code.